# Should JSON be downloaded in background?

Tags: java, android

After user press the button it fires up weather function. But it doesn't log any JSON data or any error. Should it be done in background? I've used gson libary to download JSON.

Edit: I edited my code but user must enter a city which is pasted to the link. So is it possible to run in background process when the button is tapped?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public class Download extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+strings[0]+"&APPID=****");
            URLConnection request = url.openConnection();
            request.connect();
            JsonParser jp=new JsonParser();
            JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent()));
            JsonObject rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject();
            String weather = rootobj.getAsString();
            Log.i("weather:",weather);

        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();;
        }
        return null;
    }
}


public void weather(View view){
    TextView textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String city=textView.getText().toString();
    Download download=new Download();
    download.execute(city);



}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

}

Comment: Yes. You should use Async task to manipulate your json. If for some reason the internet connection is slow, your entire app will be unresponsive until the json is proccessed.

Comment: But I have fast internet connection

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely load your data in the background. The Main Thread i.e. the UI Thread is the thread that renders the UI components so no heavy operation should be done there. If heavy operation is done in the UI Thread, it will freeze the UI.

You should look at the [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) class to perform your loading in the background.

Here is some good tutorials:

- https://alvinalexander.com/android/asynctask-examples-parameters-callbacks-executing-canceling
- https://www.journaldev.com/9708/android-asynctask-example-tutorial
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android-asynctask-example-and-explanation

Answer (score 0):

All  io operation should be executed in background ,  because all this operations are  time  consuming . which means you will block your  main thread if  you  donot execute these codes in background and may  cause Android Not Respond  exception.  IO operation in ui thread generally lead to  bad  user experience . so i strongly advice you do this  in background.

Comment: But before I do it in the background user must enter a city, which is pasted to link